# Change Permalink Structure for Tag.php template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, tags

Im using a custom post type to build a filterable gallery and taking advantage of the tags taxonomy within it. I am also using a custom taxonomy called years.

at the moment, the permalink structure of the gallery page is `www.example.com/gallery`

it is filtered by tags and years. i have made a `taxonomoy-years.php` template and used

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'archive/projects', 'with_front' => false)
```

to change the permalink structure from www.example.com/years/2000 to www.example.com/archive/projects/2000 when you filter using years.

When i filter using tags, its running off a the `tag.php` template, so the permalink structure is `www.example.com/tag/studentwork` but i would like it to be `www.example.com/archive/tag/studentwork`.

This is the code that defines my custom post type:

```
function add_post_type($name){

    add_action('init', function() use($name)  {

    register_post_type($name,array(
        'public' => true,
        'label' => ucwords($name),
        'labels' => array(
            'add_new_item' => "Add new $name item",
            'edit_item' => "Edit $name item"
        ),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),


    ));
});

}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: You shouldn't define a function with a name as generic as `add_post_type()`. Add a prefix to it, like for e.g.: `wpse_add_post_type()`.

Comment: thanks but this dosent answer my question at all.

Comment: That's why it's a comment and no answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Admin, go to `Settings > Permalinks` and under `Tag Base` add `archive/tag`.

Comment: Amazing, never even paid attention to that, thank you SO much!!! :)